# display loading image on button click

Tags: jquery, loading-image

i am trying to get a loading image on button click of login page.

and jQuery code as

```
 $('#login').click(function () {
            $.blockUI({
                message: '<img src="~/Images/loading.gif" /> <h4>Loading .......</h4>',
                timeout: 4000
            });
        });
```

i am getting text message but not the image.. please help me..
and i want this image to load on button click success..

thank you..

Comment: can you check the browser's network tab and see what URL is getting generated for `~/Images/loading.gif`. Are you getting 200 response or 404 for it?

Comment: getting 404 error for the image...@vijayP

Comment: got it by replacing "~/" with "../../"  @vijayP thank you...

Comment: thats really good...:)!